# Unfathomable behavior: UIViewController's viewWillLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, avplayer

I have:
`MyViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`

`VideoView` is a subclass of `UIView`, `aPlayer` is an instant of `AVPlayer`.  And `aPlayer.layer` is sublayer of `VideoView`'s layer.

`slider` is an instant of `UISlider` and `elapsedTimeLabel` is an instant of `UILabel`.  Both are subviews of `VideoView`.

`slider` and `elapsedTimeLabel` are define using auto layout constraints:

```
slider = UISlider()
slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderthumb.png"), for: .normal)
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderthumb.png"), for: .selected)
slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderthumb.png"), for: .highlighted)
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
controlsView.addSubview(slider)
let constraints4S = [
    slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
    slider.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
    slider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints4S)

elapsedTimeLabel = UILabel() 
elapsedTimeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
elapsedTimeLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
elapsedTimeLabel.text = "-00:00:00"
controlsView.addSubview(elapsedTimeLabel)
let constraints4L2 = [
    elapsedTimeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
    elapsedTimeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
    elapsedTimeLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.rightAnchor),
    elapsedTimeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints4L2)
```

In VideoView there is this snippet:

```
    let timeScale = CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: timeScale)
    let duration = self.aPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration
    weak var weakSelf = self
    
    // Notify every half second
    timeObserverToken = self.aPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: time,
                                                             queue: .main)
    {
        [weakSelf] time in
        weakSelf!.elapsedTimeLabel.text = stringFromCMTime(time, nil)
        weakSelf!.slider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time) / CMTimeGetSeconds(duration!))
    }
```

Issues:  In the MyViewController there is this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    mySys(myClass: self, funcName: #function)
}
```

Why is this `viewWillLayoutSubviews` got trigger continuously when `aPlayer` is playing.  After some testing, I discovered if I removed  this line then it will stop.

```
weakSelf!.elapsedTimeLabel.text = stringFromCMTime(time, nil)
```

For testing if I put a UIButton, it has the same behavior as UILabel.  But the UISlider does not.  Also If I do not use auto layout constraints then it will behavior normally.   `viewWillLayoutSubviews` from `MyUIViewController` will not called that is.

It also happened in Objective-C version.

Comment: Just a try - make the width of elapsedTimeLabel a lot bigger and see what happens.

Comment: I found [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28423083/1630618)

Comment: Good description, but this is not "unfathomable". It is _expected_. Can you explain the meaning of "why" in your question? That's just how it works. What reply would be satisfactory?

Comment: It would be nice if Auto Layout didn't get triggered for a text update to a UILabel that has a constant width and height. What's the point?

Comment: A given text may be a different size, or need to wrap, etc.  So I would not be surprised at all if the setText() method of UILabel called setNeedsLayout internally.  UILabel does not have intrinsic knowledge of what constraints it might have, and if they will be affected by different text or not -- the only way to find out is to go through a layout pass.